# How to clear previous and send only the latest value in RxJS Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

I have a grid in my Angular app where there are buttons in the row and on clicking the button, it opens the respective popup. I have created a service that has a property of `BehaviourSubject` i.e `popupEventSubject$`.

The issue I am facing is, when I open and close a popup in the row and then open another popup, the previous popup opens along side the current one. The issue I suspect is that since the `Subjects` in `RxJS` emit the previous values(when subscribed), the `BehaviourSubject` in my case is maintaining a queue of the previous events and when a subscribe is called, it displays all the events in the queue i.e open the previous popups.

So, is there a way to clear the 'queue` that is being created ?

Ideally, I am looking for my `BehaviourSubject` to work like a `AsyncSubject`, I tried replacing `BehaviourSubject` with `AsyncSubject` but it doesn't seem to emit the initial event. I tried `this.popupEventSubject$.emit(null)` in the constructor of my subject service using `AsyncSubject` but it still couldn't subscribe.

I thought of unsubscribing the subject when the popup is closed but then no other popups would open since the subject is no longer available.

Also, I want to avoid emitting `null` everytime after I emit an event to clear the `queue`.

Comment: Why not just use a regular [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject)?

Comment: could you provide some code of what you have done ?

Comment: Please provided code in some online editor would be the best. For my opinion Subject has to be enough for that example. But, please provide code and we can advice more...

Answer (score 0):

When you close the popup unsubscribe the subscription at moment, this is happpening because it time you open popup new subscription get added .So clear previous subscription first.

Comment: If I unsubscribe, then I won't be able to click on any popup anymore because I will need to re-initialize the subjects

Comment: @testsys123 Please provide some of sample code to look into issue in detail.